# How to make mk4ht not ignore biblatex and biber auxiliary files?

Tags: biblatex, biber, tex4ht

I have two TeX Live distributions installed on my system: 2014 and 2015. The 2014 distribution allows me to generate an ODT file with proper citations and bibliography by running the following:

```
latex paper
biber paper
mk4ht oolatex paper "xhtml, charset=utf-8, no^,mathml-"
```

In the 2015 distribution, however, `mk4ht` ignores `biblatex` and `biber` auxiliary files, and gives me an ODT with BibTeX keys instead of proper citations.

My question is: How can ask `mk4ht` not to ignore `biblatex` and `biber` auxiliary files in the 2015 distribution?

Here is a MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@book{Smith, title="Title", author="John Smith", year="2000"}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage
[
  backend=biber,
  citestyle=authoryear-comp, 
  bibstyle=authortitle,
]
{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Smith}.
\end{document}
```

Here is a snapshot of a ODT document compiled using `biber` and `mk4ht` from the 2014 TeX Live distribution:

[image]

And here using the 2015 distribution:

[image]

Comment: there was recently problem with new version of biblatex and tex4ht. fix should be included in current texlive, but it is possible that some styles still don't work. can you provide mwe of yout tex file?

Comment: I apologize for taking a day to anwser. I have included a MWE and snapshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you only need to update your TeX distro, your example works for me (I've added `\printbibliography`):

[image]

There were recently some problems between `biblatex` and `tex4ht`, because `tex4ht` hacks some internal `biblatex` macros in order to insert tags and these macros changed. It was more or less fixed two weeks ago, some issues still persists with non-basic styles.

Btw, you don't need to use `charset=utf-8` in `oolatex` options, this works only for HTML, `odt` is always saved in `utf-8`